# Поиск наиболее близкого элемента множества к заданному

Tags: c#, множества

> Написать функцию-шаблон поиска наиболее близкого элемента множества к заданному. Аргументами функции должны быть значение и множество.

Как решаются подобные задачи, с учетом того, что мы не можем использовать операции сравнения и т п, перегружать эти операторы или как?

Comment: Множества каких элементов? Чисел или чего?

Comment: Вам должна быть откуда-то известна операция получения расстояния между элементами. Каким образом вы её доставите вашему алгоритму — всё равно.